# Private and group chats using Ratchet and WebSockets on PHP

Tags: php, websocket, chat, ratchet

I aim to make an chat app with an option for private and group chats. I'm more used to using Ratchet and WebSockets with PHP, rather than using node.js, being that people told me that would be the best.

Though I've only seen examples of WebSockets on the context of global chats.

My approach is to use the WebSocket id and store it in the Database, for when people request to chat with a certain person or with people from a certain group, I would give the server those id's and it would send to only those people

Would that be the right way? Is there any better approach to this?

Comment: There are many protocols that can inspire when creating a chat-room and private-chat based apps. The most popular, and ripped off by companies such as Slack is [IRC protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2812). You don't have to read the RFC I linked, you can google for smaller, tl;dr version of the protocol. It will teach you how to handle messages, how to display them to appropriate party and how to approach the design of the application you described.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Ratchet, which is a good PHP library for websocket, you also read the section about [the WAMP server](http://socketo.me/docs/wamp), which is an implementation of [the WAMP protocol](http://wamp-proto.org/) (v1), about creating multiple "topics", chat room in your case.

Building a multiple channel chat server on top of WAMP protocol is a recommended start.

In your case, you also want to secure your topics. You will have to implement this security your own way, and maybe limit 2 users by topic...

A first approach could be to use tokens. When an user want to talk privatly to someone, he creates a private channel with a secret token, then he communicates this secret token to the user he wants to talk. So using the WAMP protocol, it's like creating a topic named `/chat/5sd4f5qsg8rr5sg8rg` with an enough secret token.

Another approach, more constructed, could be to store a tuple userA / userB / topic name in database, then creating the topic and allow only these two users to join it.
And when someone joins it, notify the other one (through the same websocket connection) that his friend want to talk (or open automatically the chat window...).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a socket you create a handle to a resource; you can't store the handle to the resource in a database.

What you need to do is create one-on-one client-server socket connections for each user, then distribute the chats through those connections. If a user disconnects, the socket is connection is lost and you can't send messages so you have to store in a database and then flush out when they do connect.